# Build Error using Travis CI using Eclipse ANTbuilder unable to find Class

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I'm having a problem building my software using Travis CI. It appears that I am doing all that is needed and providing what is required, but reports a problem loading my class files:

**Travis CI Project** https://travis-ci.org/Comcast/Oscar

**GitHub Project** https://github.com/Comcast/Oscar

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Ant but could it be because your `com.comcast.oscar.cli.Main` class is not compiled beforehand? Looking at this [Java template project pre configured with Junit and Ant](https://github.com/mplacona/java-junit-template-project/blob/master/build.xml) it looks like you need a `compile` step before being able to run a class. Also, does issuing `ant Main` locally on your end works?

Comment: OK, I took another look at my build.xml file after lookingat your link and did the following ant init build which worked, but... travis Cl default to a "ant test" which is not defined.  Need to either define a test option of find a way to skip "ant test"

Comment: OK, got it to work, I added the following to the .travis.yml file -> install: 
  ant init build and added to my build.xml ->     <target name="test">

    </target>